# Is it possible to call Mapper.Map inside AfterMap?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is something like this allowed somehow?

```
CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>()
    .ForMember(u => u.Password, o => o.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => {
        ...
        var entity = Mapper.Map<Entity>(src.SomeProperty);
        ...
    });
```

Is not working for me, it says that mapping tried to use inside AfterMap doesn't exist.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I notice that you are using the static `AutoMapper` class within your mapping, but are you also using the static instance outside of your mapping and does it have a mapping configured for your `Entity` class?

The below works, note that the `context.Mapper` call ensures that the same AutoMapper instance is used for both the calling `Map` and subsequent `AfterMap` methods.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<UserViewModel, User>()
       .AfterMap((source, destination, context) => 
       { 
            var entity = context.Mapper.Map<Entity>(source.SomeProperty);
       });

    cfg.CreateMap<EntityViewModel, Entity>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var viewModel = new UserViewModel
{
    Name = "Test User",
    SomeProperty = new EntityViewModel 
    { 
        Value = "Sub Class" 
    }
};

var user = mapper.Map<User>(viewModel);
```